# inserting a data in a formset passed by a form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, formset

hi I have this error in inserting a data in a formset passed by a form this is the error that appears in my browser:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: devtest_datigruppi.gruppi_scheda_id

it practically fails to see this change: groups.gruppi_scheda = Schede.objects.get (tab_name = tabName) but via print the right thing appears to me

```
schedaName = schede_form.cleaned_data['nome_scheda']
scheda = schede_form.save(commit = False)
scheda.utente = request.user
scheda.save()

 #gruppi
 if gruppi_formset.is_valid():
  for gruppi in gruppi_formset:
   gruppi.save(commit = False)
   gruppi.gruppi_scheda = Schede.objects.get(nome_scheda = schedaName)
   //print(gruppi.gruppi_scheda)
   gruppi.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the return value of  `gruppi.save(commit=False)` into a variable and update the `gruppi_scheda` property there:

```
gruppi_instance = gruppi.save(commit=False)
gruppi_instance.gruppi_scheda = Schede.objects.get(nome_scheda = schedaName)
gruppi_instance.save()
```